# Perform .loc (as reindex) on a list of dataframes and store the result as new dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I am trying to loop through a list of dataframes (list_a) and reindex them using another list (list_b). The function .loc works fine in the loop below:

```
for z,x in zip (list_a, list_b):
    z.loc([x])
```

I just have no clue how to save the result as new dataframes.

I imagine the code might start as follows:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df_list:
    for z,x in zip (df_list, regions_order):
        z.loc([x])
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot for your help!

list_a=[df1, df2]

df1 and df2 consist of an index='colors' and one column='freq' (float)

list_b=['green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'brown']

Comment: hi, if you can give some examples of the lists you mention, people here can help you better. See how to make [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, i assume `loc(` is a typo, right? It should be `loc[`?

Comment: Save them back as new list ? `new_l = [z.loc[x] for z,x in zip (list_a, list_b)]`

Comment: Hi anky, in principle exactly what I need. But it throws an error: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1):

You might be mistaking:

- `zip` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip
- and `enumerate` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

In that case, I would suggest trying this:

```py
for i, df in enumerate(list_a):
    list_a[i] = df.reindex(list_b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that did the trick. :)

Comment: No pb. If this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you wish, you can also add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle. In any case, have a nice day.